# How did this army get here?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

During "The Dragon and the Wolf" (*Game of Thrones*, S07E07),

> the Unsullied assemble outside King's Landing, and Greyworm appears in the delegation

but, as far as I remember, they were in Casterly Rock, besieged by the Greyjoy fleet.

Did I miss something? How did they get out of that situation? Is it addressed in some extra that I have not watched?

Comment: Isn't it kind of hard to be besieged by a fleet when you are on the mainland?    I don't intend to be flippant - because its disappointing they don't show the outcome of that situation explicitly - but the Unsullied could just leave Casterly Rock.  They would easily cope with a battle with the Greyjoys on land

Comment: Remember that the Riverlands were thrown into chaos at the end of season 6, when Arya killed all the Freys in the male line of descent, and the Lannister armies were decimated and scattered earlier in season 7. There are unlikely to be any organised military forces left between Casterly Rock and King's Landing to oppose the Unsullied.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Unsullied were not besieged at Casterly Rock, to be put under siege they need to be trapped from resources and escape in all directions. All the land paths from Casterly rock were free and clear.

Instead their ships were burned and destroyed while they took Casterly rock, trapping them on the far side of the mainland and forcing them to march across (and suffer the associated fatigue) if they wanted to reach anywhere useful again. It is an unfortunate situation and a tactical error, but during the time since they took Casterly rock it appears they did just that.

Comment: Also note that Euron and his fleet were back at Kings Landing too for the meeting.

Answer (score 14):

1. Casterly Rock and Kings Landing are connected by land. So, they might have just marched on land and reached there.
2. Their fleet has been destroyed by Euron's fleet. So, they **have** to march on land to reach there, and there is no other option for them.

Comment: Also I remember how Tyrion (I think) explicitly talked about how the Unsullied now had to walk back because Casterly rock had no strategic value and all the food/gold was moved out before they came.

Answer (score 1):

> they were in Casterly Rock, besieged by the Greyjoy fleet.

[Casterly Rock](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Casterly_Rock) is on the mainland of [Westeros](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Westeros), not an island.  A fleet couldn't keep them in Casterly Rock.  It could only keep them from sailing away.  The fleet burned their ships.  At that point, they could only leave by land.

At roughly the same time, the Lannisters were besieging [Highgarden](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Highgarden).  Highgarden and Casterly Rock are both about the same distance from [King's Landing](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/King%27s_Landing) by land.  And of course, there is always a road to the capital from any major castle or city.  Casterly Rock is mostly north of Highgarden and a bit to the north of King's Landing.  Highgarden is a little farther south of King's Landing but not as far west.  The point being that it is unsurprising that the Unsullied could reach King's Landing almost as quickly as the Lannister army.

The Unsullied simply had to do the same thing that Jaime's army did.  Travel by land across the width of the mainland.  This presumably required a month of travel.  They didn't depict practically any of the travel this season, which has made it difficult to keep track of time.  As far as we know, Highgarden and King's Landing are practically next to each other, while Casterly Rock could be farther away.  But in reality, both are a long way from King's Landing.